# Transaction out of gas - where are my ethers?

Tags: out-of-gas

I sent 2 ethers to indahash for an ico and the Transaction ran out of gas. Indahash say they dont have them, they are not in my wallet and this happened 18 days ago.I'd like to get the ethers either to indahash or back to my wallet.

Answer (score 3):

I believe there are only three possible outcomes:

- Ether stayed in your wallet.
- Ether got transferred to another account/contract. This can be split into two cases:

  - Sent to correct account/contract.
  - Sent to incorrect account/contract.

Ether cannot be stuck in limbo in the way you seem to think it might be. You can look at the transaction on the blockchain to figure out where there ethers ended up. I suppose there's a third (unlikely) outcome: you set a very high gas limit and/or price and a relatively small transaction and you spent all your ether on gas, so it went to the miners in the form of a transaction fee. But you should have seen that one a mile away with any of the mainstream wallet programs.

If you find your transaction ID/hash (the same thing) and search for it on https://etherscan.io, you can see what happened to the transaction.

Comment: So how do I look for the transaction on the blockchain? Can I pay someone to help me with this?

Comment: In the wallet you used to send the transaction (assuming the wallet is even only half-decent), you should be able to find the transaction id. You can plug the transaction ID into the search field of https://etherscan.io to see lots of information about the transaction. If you need help interpreting that info and you don’t mind being able to have your real-works identity linked to your ethereum account and your past/future transactions with that account, you can post the transaction ID here.

Comment: As for paying someone, this stack exchange is a place for people to help one another out (and to seek help) free of charge. You can pay it forward by doing something nice for a stranger today as payment for “services” here. If you really want to give monetary remuneration, some of us have ethereum or other cryptocurrency wallet addresses listed in our profiles where you can send a tip.

Comment: I used myetherwallet and I do not see a transaction ID only TxHash. Is that the ID?

Comment: Yes, that's the thing you're looking for!

Comment: 0x46364adcf5919aa92028bb271d48726508175134b65b926c9f5185153709588d

Comment: I think you're missing a few characters there... (six to be exact)

Comment: 0x46364adcf5919aa92028bb271d48726508175134b65b926c9f5185153709588d is all I have

Comment: Oh... weird. Can you please post your account address (this is safe to share, so long as you're okay with us knowing how much you have in that account and your past/future transaction history for it)? Do NOT post your private keys anywhere. If you're unsure, don't hesitate to ask. It's better to be safe than sorry! Your address should be on the right hand side of MEW. It's ~40 characters long. Your private key (DO NOT SHARE) is roughly 60 characters long.

Comment: Alternately, you can see transaction history for yourself by searching for your account on https://etherscan.io .

Comment: 0xf6db97f9c93e64891e2d0ffff8afa479ff5c5bfc

Comment: Okay: got it! You can go to https://etherscan.io/address/0xf6db97f9c93e64891e2d0ffff8afa479ff5c5bfc and see your transaction history. Here's what happened: Nov 28, you deposited ~10.04ETH into the account. On Dec 1, you tried to transfer 2 ETH to IndaHash; this failed due to being out of gas. Your account had ~10.04ETH after this (i.e., you paid a small amount of transaction fees and that's it). You got your 2 ETH back in full (or, more precisely, it never left). Dec 10: you transferred 10ETH to 0x19280c653961758ea1c2e400da6802d3600e759d (an exchange?), so your final balance is about 0.04 ETH.

Comment: I really appreciate all your work. Thank you very much!